# Matplotlib does not show plot on Mac in non-interactive mode

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, pycharm

I have carefully searched solutions online, but I couldn't solve the problem.

I am using Mac OS X High Sierra, with the latest version of python (installed with the official installer) and matplotlib package (installed using pip).

I am also sure that I have set 'TkAgg' as backend, as many other users suggest. Let us talk with the following sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show(block=True)
```

The code works in interactive mode, and the plot just popped up properly. However, I found that this does not work no matter what I do, or no matter which part of the code I change. pylab (as others suggested) did not work either. For example, if I run the code using

```
python test.py
```

it will just quit without showing anything. Same thing also happened in PyCharm.

Update: I just debugged the code, and found that matplotlib blocks the window deliberately?! 
In file

```
PYTHON_PATH/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py
```

lines 195-196 show

```
if cls.mainloop is None:
    return
```

which should be that, if we are in non-interactive mode, it will just return. When I comment these 2 lines, it raises `NonGuiException()`.

I am afraid that we cannot solve it at the moment?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. I ran the script in non-interactive mode from terminal and the plot pops out just fine. But I am not on Mac OS. I am on Linux.

Comment: @AmitSingh I debugged the code, and saw that it seems that matplotlib will just return when I'm not in interactive mode... And the code in this file is completely different from what it is on Windows! Really shocked me...

Comment: "it raises NonGuiException()" seems to indicate you don't have a backend set, contrary to your expectations. Perhaps try explicitly setting it in your example code: `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` (just before importing pyplot).

Comment: @Evert Thank you for your answer but it still wouldn't work. It just returned before it plotted or do anything.

Comment: Puzzling. Can you explain what you mean by "interactive mode" (where it does work)? Just update your question with the precise step(s) you use. Because I wonder if it's the exact same Python executable (and same environment).

Comment: @Andy sorry for the delay in replying. I checked the code for the `show()` function in Linux and it is the same as what you have reported. But still when I run the script from command line, the plot pops out. So I am  not sure if that is the cause.

Comment: @AmitSingh Sorry for delay too. Yes that is the case. So far, it is still able to savefig properly, so I think at the moment, I'm just gonna save it as pdf and then check it.